# Why is the macro-name not painted blue?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c99

Say I have the following two macro definitions:

```
#define foo(X) 1 bar
#define bar(X) 2 foo
```

Why does `foo(X)(Y)(Z)` expand to `1 2 1 bar`?

According to the C99 standard 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement

> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of
> the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s
> preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested
> replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not
> replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no
> longer available for further replacement even if they are later
> (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token
> would otherwise have been replaced.

So the way these tokens seems to be translated is the following sequence

```
foo(X)(Y)(Z)
1 bar(Y)(Z)
1 2 foo(Z)
1 2 1 bar
```

So apparently the second macro invocation of `foo` doesn't get painted blue. I am somewhat unsure why this is actually the case. Isn't it part of the replacement caused by the invocation of `bar` which would make it a nested replacement of the replacement of the first invocation of `foo`.

I can only argue that the way these expansions work is that the tokens that cause the macro invocations of both `foo` and `bar` are partially in the nested replacement, i.e. the name of the macro is inside it and partially outside of the replacement, i.e. the parenthesis part is outside the replacement.

Or perhaps I am completely misunderstanding the meaning of nested replacement.

Can somebody be so kind to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 replacement stages here. First happens during argument substitution, which happens in isolation from rest of the file:

> #### 6.10.3.1 Argument substitution
>
> 1. After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument
>    substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless
>    preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ##
>    preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding
>    argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. **Before
>    being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely
>    macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file;**
>    no other preprocessing tokens are available.

Second stage, rescanning, happens after macro and it's arguments have been expanded:

> #### 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> 1. **After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted** and # and ## processing has
>    taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. Then,
>    **the resulting preprocessing token sequence is rescanned, along with
>    all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file**, for more macro
>    names to replace.

Paragraph you are referring to applies only to the first stage, argument substitution:

> 2. If the name of the macro being replaced is found
>    during this **scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of
>    the source file’s preprocessing tokens),** it is not replaced. ...

Since your macros `foo` and `bar` don't use their arguments, you are only seeing effects of the rescanning phase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think I agree with or understand your deduction. I really think that 'this scan' is referring to the replacement of the parameters in the replacement list which is described in point 1. as you have quoted yourself in your answer. Point 1. describes a scan and replacement phase of the expanded parameters in the replacement list. And point 2. immediately follows point 1. So 'this scan' must identify with the replacement list scan described previously in point 1.

Comment: @ArisKoning `foo`'s replacement list (as in: "After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted") is: `1 bar`.  That replacement list does not contain a `bar` invocation.  `foo` is painted blue while 6.10.3.4p2 ("scan of the replacement list", also note "not including the rest of the source file's preprocessing tokens") occurs.  Then, it's done, and `foo` is unpainted.  Then you have `1 bar (Y)(Z)`.  *Then* you have `bar (Y)` which is an invocation of `bar`; that invocation is not part of foo's rescan and replacement.

Comment: Just for clarity, recap for the case `#define foo(X) 1 bar(X)`, `#define bar(x) 2 foo(X)`, `#define A 7`.  invoke with `foo(A)`.  Now `foo`'s replacement list is `1 bar(X)`.  Argument substitution (a.s.) occurs, and you get `1 bar(7)`.  `foo` is then painted blue, then rescan and further replacement (r.a.f.r.) occurs.  `bar(7)` is now an invocation, that's nested.  a.s. of `bar` produces `2 foo(7)`.  Then r.a.f.r. of bar occurs; `bar` is now painted.  Now you just get `2 foo(7)`, because `foo` is still painted.  So the result is `1 2 foo(7)`.  Then `bar` is unpainted, then `foo`.

Comment: During the scan after the parameter replacement, `bar` is encountered inside of the expanded replacement list and the parenthesized part `(Y)` is outside of this replacement list. The macro expansion of `bar(Y)` is apparently not interpreted as a nested replacement by the clang and gcc preprocessor. So what is the definition of a nested replacement? This is not found in the standard. This is where the standard becomes ambigious. It should specify what happens to a macro-invocation whose token sequence overlaps with but is not a strict subsequence of the expanded replacement list.

Comment: Nesting has the common meaning.  There's a r.a.f.r. step, during which something evaluates.  That evaluation can invoke macros.  Such invocations "start over", but they are still in the process of evaluating the r.a.f.r.; hence they are "nested".

Comment: Maybe this would help.  Consider `#define foo(x) x foo`, then `foo(A)(B)`.  `foo(A)` is an invocation; a.s. occurs, making `A foo`.  Then r.a.f.r.; only now, that `foo` is painted blue, but whereas that's not a `foo` invocation, it is "the name of the macro being replaced".  So you get `A foo(B)`.  Now `foo(B)` is an invocation, but `foo` is ineligible for expansion per 6.10.3.4p2 "These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacements even if they are later (re)examined"; but by contrast no such thing happens in your case (no foo during foo).

Comment: Your example is not exactly touching my issue, because as you have said the token `foo` in the expansion of `foo(A)` is painted blue. It can never be part of any macro invocation ... period. My example circumvents that short-cutting paint job and touches more replacement mechanics. Again I think the standard should specify more clearly what counts as nested replacement. The behavior of actual preprocessors is perfectly sensible (and useful). But I still don't think it follows from the standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217109/discussion-between-h-walters-and-aris-koning).