# rescan for macro replacement?

Tags: c++, macros, c99

By reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680235/why-is-the-macro-name-not-painted-blue)
(where I cannot add comments-questions as I am new on StackOverflow),
it is explained that with the definitions

```
#define foo(X) 1 bar
#define bar(X) 2 foo
```

then

```
foo(X)(Y)(Z)
```

expands to

```
1 2 1 bar
```

In particular, the additional comment by @ H Walters on Jul 2, 2020 at 14:36 (see link [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680235/why-is-the-macro-name-not-painted-blue)) reads
*foo's replacement list (as in: "After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted") is: 1 bar. That replacement list does not contain a bar invocation. foo is painted blue while 6.10.3.4p2 ("scan of the replacement list", also note "not including the rest of the source file's preprocessing tokens") occurs. **Then, it's done, and foo is unpainted**. Then you have 1 bar (Y)(Z). Then you have bar (Y) which is an invocation of bar; that invocation is not part of foo's rescan and replacement.*

So, my question is:
why in this other scenario the same seems not to apply ?

```
#define t(a) a
```

then

```
t(t)(1)
```

expands to

```
t(1)
```

...that is, 't' seems to remain painted.
Even the standard shows this case (as part of a more complex example, here I just extracted the nutshell I wanted to focus on).

An important detail: I look for it in C++ while the original post was on C99, but I guess it is the same.
Anyway, on g++ both scenarios work as explained above.

To recap:

```
#define t(a) a
#define k(a) a

k(t)(k)(1) -> expands to: 1 [both k and t never remain painted]
t(t)(1) -> expands to: t(1) [t remains painted]
t(t)(t)(t)(1) -> expands to t(t)(t)(1) [t remains painted after first replacement]
```

Comment: Could be useful: https://github.com/notfoundry/ppstep

Comment: yeah, I'll try to play with it, but I was asking also about standard words interpretation on the subject.

Comment: Can you please clarify what language you're asking about? You have the `c99` tag for that standard but `c++` for the language.

Comment: sure, C++: as commented "I look for it in C++ while the original post was on C99".

I find that in C++17 standard the section 19.3.4 reads at the same way of the words written in the original post, for example "If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest
of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced..."

So, I guess that the explanation would work for both C++ and C99 and tagged both of them. Anyway, my focus is on C++.